# What is correct relative path in my project?

Tags: java, file, path

I need to specify relative path to images/tabIcon.gif in java.

I am in class `FileViewerManager` and I need to create new File that has relative path to images/tabIcon.gif.

My code is :

```
File file = new File("./images/tabIcon.gif");
```

My project structure is :

src/model/FileViewerManager

src/images/tabIcon.gif

My code doesn't work because `file.exists` returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I'm assuming FileViewerManager in your project structure is a file):

```
File file = new File("../images/tabIcon.gif");
```

If it is a folder, you'll need to go up an additional directory:

```
File file = new File("../../images/tabIcon.gif");
```